# Do Weyl groups generate the exceptional Lie groups as sequences of reflexions in the Weyl chambers?

Tags: coxeter-groups, weyl-group, exceptional-groups

Platonic groups of symmetry are Weyl groups for the exceptional Lie algebra E6->E8, as root systems. These can be viewed as mirrors in a kaleidoscope ([Goodman](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Egoodman/pub/monthly.pdf)).
I would like to know if one can generate E6-E8 Lie groups as Coxeter groups in this way (representing their elements as a product of reflexions in the mirrors of such a 3D Weyl group, associated to Platonic groups of symmetry, as a root system).
I recall that there is an article studying the paths of multiple reflections in such Weyl systems as kaleidoscopes; does anybody know it?

Comment: No, Lie groups cannot be realized as Coxeter groups. They are very different things (though related in certain ways…)

Comment: Is there a way to relate the groupoid of reflection paths in Weil chambers and the exceptional Lie group? or it rather has to do with its representation theory?